# post запрос Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, html5

вроде написано всё правильно, но при нажатии кнопки я получаю не объединенную строку, а ошибку, как это можно поправить? 
Notice: Undefined index: country 
Notice: Undefined index: type 
Notice: Undefined index: newdate

```html
файл index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



  <form action="10.php" method="post" id="reg-form">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="type" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Тип
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="type" name="prog">
          <li><a href="#" data-value="1">Волонтерская</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="2">Проф</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="5">стартап</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="country" name="reg" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Страна
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="country">
          <li><a href="#" data-value="1542"> Италия</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="1562">Корея</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="504">Вьетнам</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="btn-group">
        <input id="newdate" type="date" value="2011-01-13" name="eard" class="btn btn-info " />
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="post-btn">Подобрать</button>
      </div>

      <div id="parent"><b>подгрузка данных</b></div>
    </div>
  </form>


  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/asc.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
      $($(this).parents(".btn-group")[0]).find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
      $($(this).parents(".btn-group")[0]).find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
    });



    $("#post-btn").click(function() {
      $.post("10.php", $('#reg-form').serialize(), function(data) {
        $mydata = (data);
        document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = $mydata;
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
файл 10. php

<?php  
$country=$_POST["country"];
$type=$_POST["type"];
$newdate=$_POST["newdate"];

echo  $country .  $type .  $newdate;

?>
```

Comment: Так что тут правильного? Вы данные с формы не отправляете, поэтому и нотисы на стороне сервере. Почитайте как работать с формами в php

Comment: я отправляю, вот же код     $("#post-btn").click(function () {
        $.post("10.php", $('#reg-form').serialize(), function (data) {
            $mydata = (data);
            document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = $mydata;
        });
    });

Comment: Так а что вы отправляете? Ничего. Вызовите в консоли браузера $('#reg-form').serialize() и увидите

Comment: ну я ищу по id="reg-form" элемент и сливаю его запросом, а почему ничего не отправляется?

Comment: потому что не `id` надо кнопкам заполнять а имена `name`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в атрибутах, на сервер названием переменной передается атрибут `name`, а не `id`, то есть получаем след. код в странах:

```
<button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="country" name="country" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Страна
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="country">
      <li><a href="#" data-value="1542"> Италия</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="1562">Корея</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="504">Вьетнам</a></li>
    </ul>
```